# setOnItemClickListener in dialog is not working

Tags: android, android-listview

My list will show in the dialog when user click the button and I want to
check the item that user

click but it's not working. My code is as following:

```
private void showEditImageList() {
    final String names[] ={"A","B","C","D","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t"};
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SlotInformationActivity.this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_image_list, null);
    //convertView.setClickable(true);
    //convertView.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);

    alertDialog.setView(convertView);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Tools");

    ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editImageList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    lv.setClickable(true);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            System.out.println("Click position:" + position);
        }
    });


    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Please help and thank you.

For the code in file  `edit_image_list.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/editImageList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to remove setClickable() from your ListView. Not sure, but maybe interception of event occurs here and onItemClick doesn't fire.

Comment: Also instead of System.out.println(); use Log.d("MY_APP","Click position:"+position); and select debug option in logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this code will solve your problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/editImageList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**update:** 
[image]

Comment: Oh my gosh !!! That's work. Thank you so much. Would you mind explain me how and why, please?

Comment: Well when you set it to width to wrap_content the list was wraping it where letter was ending not to screen  full width, try running your previous code and click exactly on alphabets they are clickable but rest area is just blank